# Regular expression which allows all characters except for "<>_ ;{}[]"

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I need a regular expression in javascript which allows all characters except for following characters `<>_ ;{}[]`

Following is the regular expression which i have tried this[regex] checks for allowed characters.

```
"^[A-Za-z0-9\s~!@#$%^&amp;*()|\&quot;\':?\/.+=,.-]*$"
```

but it is failing for following string **~!@#$%^&*()|\"':?/.,ab-=12+**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not use a negated class instead of putting all of them in a character class? It's easier to read and faster in execution.

```
/^[^<>_ ;{}\[\]]+$/
```

Just use `RegExp.test` with the above regex.

Comment: you need to escape the special characters like `[]{}` so `/^[^<>_ ;\{\}\[\]]+$/`

Comment: @Luceos AFAIK inside character class only `[]-` (as well as `/`) characters should be escaped. Any other characters have no special mean there

Comment: @hindmost yup. `{}` doesn't need to be escaped.

Comment: i was unaware of that; nice ;)